# Implement Web solution as Winform

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection

A few time ago I developed a win for app based on primary start app, meaning it's an application which able to load user profile and other stuff, such as username, surname, mail address, granted actions, printing-anabled, saveing-enabled and so on). Then, my co-worker are free to develop any other application as DLL which are loaded via reflection by my primary application where it's able to load any form as mdi child. That's all. Finally, every primary app command being realying on child form which implements some interface so all works perfectly.

Well, now I need to convert the above logic on new web site solution. Think of that where my primary startup app could be "thought" as master page. Here, I can load info user (user profile) and other stuff such as application enabled he is, printing page-enabled, data storing-enabled and so on.
By the way, my co-worker should be able to develop other "sub web site" reached by my primary start-up (master page).
Also, both of them should comunicate in order to realy some command, for instance: user click on masterpage save button, then storing db action will relay to content page (just as win form solution).

I don't know which can be better solution fort this purpose, I hope to be clear to explain my scenario.

Comment: Your requirement is not very clear, are you looking for a solution to reuse the logic you have developed for WinForms in WebForms or you are asking for a suggestion about how to implement reusable components in web application (asp.net)?

Comment: your second one. I would to build an asp.net application where it is possibile make easy dialog between primary app (my website, my master page) and any other asp.net control covered in a bin\dllname. All my world will start from my master page (same skin, same logic), but any programmer will be able to build some "sub site" to inject on my web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As vague as the requirement seems from the question... I think you should look into developing your applications in tiers (layers). If you have your business and persistence logic in a way that they are not coupled to any graphical interface, then turning a windows application into an asp.net one is much, much easier.